# Architecture/Optimization of a scheduling problem on OptaPlanner

Tags: drools, optaplanner, kie

I'd like to generate a planning with OptaPlanner, with the following problem :

- "Task" is the planning entity

  - It has a fixed duration
  - It has an employee (planning variable) which must match required skills
  - It has a workstation (planning variable) which must match required attributes
  - It has dependencies: some tasks must start after some others
  - Some tasks have a deadline

At first, I tried with chained/shadow variables, basing on the OptaPlanner Task Assignment example. On my first attempt, I kept the employee as an anchor, and let the workstation management to the solver:

[image: Employee task]

I quickly saw that there was a problem with this approach. Here, Task A and Task B (and all others) have an influence the one on the other while they are not on the same chain and also the previous element of the chain has not enough information to determine the start time of the task. Also, the worst thing is that workstations changes not being tracked in this model, the solutions are just non-sense as workstations can be used several times.

To fix the problem of workstation tracking, I added workstations to the anchor and made all employee/workstation combinations

[image: Employee-workstation task]

This way I know the employee and workstation on each chain. However this does not solve the problem of start time of tasks on a chain being dependent on tasks on other chains (e.g, Task A and Task D share the same workstation) and therefore Task insertions/removals shall have repercussion on other chains, which is not the spirit.

I ended giving up the idea of chained variables as it seems that their usage does not fit my problem.

So I modified my classes and the start time of tasks is now resolved with all intelligence left to OptaPlanner's solver, driven by pure drools rules and a ValueRangeProvider.

When I have only the following rules :

- No employee recovery (Hard)
- No workstation recovery (Hard)
- Skills and attributes requirements (Hard)
- Tasks with deadlines ending before deadline (Soft, could be Medium)
- Tasks ending as soon as possible (sum of squared end times, Soft)

I can get quite fast a solution that seems to be the best.

However, when I add dependencies between tasks (with a hard rule going down task dependencies to see if a dependency does not end after the task starts), the complexity seems to dramatically increase so for a few dozens task, with only 2 operators, 3 workstations, a satisfying solution (without an unexpected holes between tasks) can take an hour to come, with the following parameters:

- Experiment length: 10,000 min
- Granularity: 1 min

I also have a TaskDifficultyComparator to help the solver place the hardest tasks before

This is very long for a few tasks and it will be far worse when inserting a notion of availability of user, I even suspect it never converges as task end time will "jump" depending on availabilities.

So my questions are:

- Are there solutions leveraging chained variables that would suit my problem?
- Are their any optimizations on the solver/rules/something else that could grant me a precious speed-up?